# Cocoa: NSView not drawing rect

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have a class called ServerImage (sub of NSView) which I am calling from my AppController but for some reason it won't draw to the screen. I have other views which I am able to draw and add images to but for some reason not this one. I'm sure I am missing something in my code but am just not seeing it. Here's the relevant code from AppController:

```
//loop through masterServerDict and get server status   
NSMutableString* key; 
for(key in masterServerDict) { 

    ServerImage* newImage = [[ServerImage alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200.0, 0.0, 48.0, 48.0)];

    [newImage setServerName:key];
    [[[NSApp mainWindow] contentView] addSubview:newImage];
    [newImage setNeedsDisplay:YES];


}
```

masterServerDict is a mutable dictionary, the key is the name of a server, the object is an array, it holds the smb and afp paths to the server and whether it is mounted or not.

Here is ServerImage.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


    @interface ServerImage : NSView {

        NSString * serverName; 
    }

    - (void) setServerName : (NSString* ) s; 

@end
```

and ServerImage.m

```
#import "ServerImage.h"


@implementation ServerImage

    - (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code here.
            NSLog(@"%f", self.frame.origin.x);
        }

        return self;
    }

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawrect");
    [[NSColor redColor] set]; 
    NSRectFill(rect);
}

- (void) setServerName : (NSString* ) s { 
    NSLog(@"method");
    serverName = s; 

}
```

I can get the init and setServerName methods to log but not drawRect...

Answer (score 0):

Check if `[[NSApp mainWindow] contentView]` is non-nil. Also check if it refers to the right window and that the coordinate is good (visible).

Comment: Check if [[NSApp mainWindow] contentView] is non-nil - do I just log it? I did log it from AppController and I got (null) but I'm not sure what I should be expecting to see.

Comment: You can also assert it: `assert([NSApp mainWindow] != nil);`

Comment: The app is 1000x610, not flipped so the x=200.0, y=0.0 coordinate is good, should be somewhere in the lower left. There's only one window and I am using the default reference (mainWindow).